# Python: Square and exponential interpolation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I have the following question,

I have a huge 3D matrix and want to map ranges of numbers to other number ranges. There are some conditions I have to follow. For example in some cases I need to interpolate the first range linear and the second range quadtratic or exponential. The calculation has to be very fast For linear interpolation in the whole range I can do this by flatten the matrix, do scipys interp1d and reshape the matrix after this. For this example the matrix already flattened and only a small range of x Values. The real matrix has around 150000-20000 x Values:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

xValues=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
interpolateFunction = interp1d([0,2,2.01,6],[-15,-1,15,1],fill_value=0,bounds_error=False)
print(interpolationFunction(xValues))
```

Now I would like to know if there is any possiblity to do that also for square and exponential functions instead of linear how interp1d do it and to treat multi ranges differently like i explained above. For example I want to interpolate the range [0,2] linear to    [-15,-1] and the range [2.01,6] exponential  to [-15,-1]. For a linear and quadtratic case it could look like this (sorry for the painting):

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are after, can you provide the expected result for your input and a square and exponential interpolation? -[mcve] - Have you tried a linear interpolation of the log of your input then then converting the interpolated values back using the log base?

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to turn a formula [like this](http://www.pmean.com/10/ExponentialInterpolation.html) into code?

Comment: `interp1d` can do varying orders of spline interpolation is that good enough?

Comment: @wwii What exactly does this spline Interpolation?

Comment: `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` - you have read its documentation right?

Comment: And there is also [`numpy polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit) and [`scipy curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) BTW, posted code should at least have a valid syntax.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i edited the question :)

Comment: @wwii how would this linear interpolation of the log of the inout and converting it with log base look like in numpy? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you intentionally want the interpolated function to be discontinuous at x=2, but I think the following code will do what you want (assuming you've unwrapped your 3D tensor into a 1D array):

```
linearFn = interp1d([0, 2], [-15, -1], fill_value='extrapolate')
gain = 0.25 * np.log(15)

linearVals = linearFn(xValues)
expoVals = -15 * np.exp(-gain * (xValues - 2))
interpolated = np.where(xValues <= 2, linearVals, expoVals)
```

The exponential bit of the interpolated function is assumed to have the form y=-15*exp(-(x-2)*log(15)/4), which agrees with your boundary conditions at x=2 and x=6.

If you apply this to `xValues = np.linspace(0, 6, 100)`, you get a graph like this:
[image]

Comment: But where do you use your expoFn function?.

Comment: Good point, it's not needed. Indeed, we don't really need the other interp1d if we're just doing linear interpolation.

Comment: Nice! Would the same be possible if the linear interpolation goes like above from 0 ,2 to values -15,-1 bit the exponential from 2,6 to 15,1. So beginning with the highstest value to the lowest?

Comment: There's nothing special about the y-values of those interpolation points, so the structure of the code would be exactly the same. Obviously, the exact form of the exponential function would need to be changed, and the parameters to the interp1d() used to calculate linearVals.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I need a version/function of the exponential interpolation where i can vary the numbers to shich the x Values should be interpolated. For example isntead of -15,-1, possible other ranges would be [-15,1] or [3,30] or [-20,20]. Is that possible? I have a version but it has problems with the log of the negative values:

y = np.exp(np.log(interV1)+np.log(interV2/interV1)*((x-border1) / (border2-border1))) where border 1 = 0, border2 = 2, interV1 = -15 and interV2 = -1 for the example above.

Comment: As you've observed, it isn't possible to fit an exponential function (with real arguments) to two y-values that are on either side of the x-axis. If you're fitting a function of the form a.exp(-alpha.x), then alpha would have to be a complex number to allow your interpolated function to cross the x-axis. You could try a function of the form (a-y0).exp(-alpha.x), where y0 is some constant smaller than the y-value of the point with smallest magnitude.